# pipe redirection issue, lost data

Tags: c, unix, pipe

I want to reproduce this shell behaviour with a small c program:

```
< file cmd1 | cmd2
```

So it takes three arguments and can be executed this way for exemple:

```
./a.out foo /bin/cat /usr/bin/wc
```

Here's my code, without error checking:

```
#include <unistd.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <fcntl.h>

static void exe_cmd(char *cmd, char **env)
{
    int     pid;
    char    *av[] = {cmd, NULL};

    pid = fork();
    if (pid == 0)
    {
        execve(av[0], av, env);
        exit(0);
    }
    waitpid(pid, NULL, 0);
}

static void left_pipe_side(int fd[2], char *cmd, char *path, char **env)
{
    int file;

    file = open(path, O_RDONLY);
    dup2(fd[1], STDOUT_FILENO); // Can be commented out to see the first command output
    dup2(file, STDIN_FILENO);
    close(fd[0]);
    close(fd[1]);
    close(file);
    exe_cmd(cmd, env);
}

static void right_pipe_side(int fd[2], char *cmd, char **env)
{
    dup2(fd[0], STDIN_FILENO);
    close(fd[1]);
    close(fd[0]);
    exe_cmd(cmd, env);
}

int main(int ac, char **av, char **env)
{
    int fd[2];
    pid_t   pid;

    pid = fork();
    pipe(fd);
    if (pid == 0)
    {
        left_pipe_side(fd, av[2], av[1], env);
        exit(0);
    }
    right_pipe_side(fd, av[3], env);
    waitpid(pid, NULL, 0);
    return (0);
}
```

My problem is that the output of `wc` as the second command will always be `0   0   0`, as if the input were empty (but the given file contains text).
If I comment out the line where I dup fd[1] to stdout in the left pipe side, the first command will output correctly, so I don't understand why the redirection makes this data "disappear"

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You open `pipe` after `fork`, so each process has it's own very *unrelated* `pipe`. Open it before, so that it's shared between processes.

```
pipe(fd);
pid = fork();
```

Answer (score 0):

in your code, you open the `pipe` after the `fork` so that's mean every process has its own `pipe` and that's not how pipes work

you have to open the `pipes` before the `fork` that's make the process linked with your pipe.

```
#include <unistd.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <fcntl.h>

static void exe_cmd(char *cmd, char **env)
{
    int     pid;
    char    *av[] = {cmd, NULL};

    pid = fork();
    if (pid == 0)
    {
        execve(av[0], av, env);
        exit(0);
    }
    waitpid(pid, NULL, 0);
}

static void left_pipe_side(int fd[2], char *cmd, char *path, char **env)
{
    int file;

    file = open(path, O_RDONLY);
    dup2(fd[1], STDOUT_FILENO); // Can be commented out to see the first command output
    dup2(file, STDIN_FILENO);
    close(fd[0]);
    close(fd[1]);
    close(file);
    exe_cmd(cmd, env);
}

static void right_pipe_side(int fd[2], char *cmd, char **env)
{
    dup2(fd[0], STDIN_FILENO);
    close(fd[1]);
    close(fd[0]);
    exe_cmd(cmd, env);
}

int main(int ac, char **av, char **env)
{
    int fd[2];
    pid_t   pid;
    /************************ the error part **********************/
    // pid = fork();
    // pipe(fd);
    pipe(fd);
    pid = fork();
    /**************************************************************/

    if (pid == 0)
    {
        left_pipe_side(fd, av[2], av[1], env);
        exit(0);
    }
    right_pipe_side(fd, av[3], env);
    waitpid(pid, NULL, 0);
    return (0);
}
```